# Simple Grammar questions

Tags: grammar

While checking students´ answers of the midterm exams, I found out various answers and I wonder if it´s grammatically correct. Could you please check if these answers can be possible?

★ The right answer is: Minsu, my best friend, is very kind.
and those are the answers of my students...

1. Minsu my best friend is very kind. (he did't write comma)
2. Minsu, my best friend is very kind.(he only wrote one comma)

★ The right answer is: Would you say that(it) again? 
and those are the answers of my students...

1. Would you say again please?
2. Would you please talk again?
3. Would you say me again?
4. Would you say onemore time?(he wrote 'one more' without any space)
5. Would you speak to me?
6. Would you speak to again?
7. Would you tell me what?
8. Would you tell me again?
9. Would you say to again?
10. Would you say me again?
11. Would you speak that again?
12. Would you tell that again?

★ The right answer is: My favorite color is blue. 
and those are the answers of my students...

1. My favorite color is blue most.
2. My favorite color is blue color.
3. My favorite color is blue in most.
4. My favorite color is like blue.
5. My favorite color is like blue color.

★ The right answer is:  I have seen many plays.

1. I have watched many plays.
2. I have been many plays.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *"I have watched many plays"*.

Comment: I have *been to* many plays. Maybe partial credit :-)

Comment: "Would you tell me again?" is a well-formed English request: *I've forgotten the street address. Would you tell me again?*

Comment: And Blue-4 is like totes cromulent, dude, if they're supposed to be mastering the vernacular.

Comment: "my best fried" should be "my best friend".  I hope this is a typo.

Comment: In this context, "Would you" can be replaced by "Would you please" or just "Please".

Comment: Though its correctness is debatable, i've heard "say again?" often enough to make "Would you say again please?" sound quite normal to me.

Answer (score 1):

> (1). Would you say again please?

`say` tends to require an object. (Would you say that again please)

> (2). Would you please talk again?
>
> (5). Would you speak to me?

This could be correct, but it has slightly different meaning: Would you say something/participate in a dialog

> (3). Would you say me again?
>
> (10). Would you say me again?

`me` here implies that `tell` should be used, not `say`. (Would you tell me again)

> (4). Would you say onemore time?(he wrote 'one more' without any space)

`onemore` is incorrect. And an object is desirable (Would you say it one more time)

> (6). Would you speak to again?
>
> (9). Would you say to again?

`to` doesn't agree to `again`.

> (8). Would you tell me again?

Looks to be correct.

> (11). Would you speak that again?

Rather incorrect. `say` should be here.

> (12). Would you tell that again?

Incorrect, `tell` requires `me`. `say` would be perfect here.

[Example with `say` and `speak`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPHuE5pDlEs)

Comment: "Would you speak to me?" is grammatically correct, but does not mean "Please repeat that."  Instead, it means "Would you talk to me?" or "Are we on speaking terms?"

Comment: Could you please comment on the 7th one?

Comment: "Would you tell me what?" sounds like either "Would you tell me... What?" or the start of "Would you tell me what you mean?"  So it is not correct as written, but a native speaker might interpret it more-or-less correctly.  The listener might think the person thought it was unbelievable, instead of just hard-to-hear.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your detailed comments!

Answer (score 1):

> (1). My favorite color is blue most.
>
> (3). My favorite color is blue in most.

Rather incorrect. I doubt what `most` is intended to mean here.
`In most` could possibly mean `at most`.

> (2). My favorite color is blue color.

Maybe correct, but not perfect. The second `color` is redundant.

> (4). My favorite color is like blue.

Correct if `like` means `similar to`.

> (5). My favorite color is like blue color.

Has the issues of both 2 and 4.

Comment: I think you meant "The second *color* is redundant."  (*Abundant* means "plentiful", and is a good thing; *redundant* means "excessive", and is a bad thing.)

Comment: @Jasper, thx, fixed both :)

Comment: I think your comment on (5) would be clearer if you said "has the issues of both 2 and 4".